# 360° product rotation effect on mouse scroll

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any plugin to obtain an effect like this one?

[Polaroid rotation](http://www.3sessanta.it/home.php#rotation)

I notice that is a huge image with some photos stitched together, I can create this type of photo but I want to animate them on page scrolling!

Can I obtain this effect usin only CSS?

Comment: Short answer: no. This is because the background position is determined by how far the user scroll, and that is calculated by JS.

Comment: Wow that site is buggy.  You sure you want a site that works that badly?  Make a good site instead.

Comment: doing it with js it's easy an is the way to go... but you can do it only with CSS too, just like http://www.romancortes.com/blog/pure-css-coke-can/ my jsfiddle is on the way...

Comment: @coma  the can trick is really nicely done 8)

Comment: I know that the site is buggy! By the way I create a turntable that can automatically shoot product pictures from various angle and I want to obtain a similar effect using the scrollin of the page as input for the scroll! :)

Comment: @coma are you still trying? :)

Comment: hehehe, nope, sorry... the coke can image is continuous so it can be applied as a texture, on the other hand the polaroid camera sequence needs a discrete changing so you'll need to use js... my english is very basic so I hope I've been clear. Would you like the js version?. No scrolling but is cool: http://jsfiddle.net/coma/BZajk/11/

Comment: @coma that's cool but you use several images!. But I have to load only one image with all the  product pictures angles stitched together! And I also want to animate it with scrolling. I'm looking for some js library without any success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Terry already said, you need some js help because you have to translate a continuous changing (scroll position in px) to a discrete or stepped changing (the image position):

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/sBTzG/13/

**HTML**

```
<div id="rotator"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    height: 2000px;
}

#rotator {
    font-size: 416px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: transparent url(http://www.3sessanta.it/images/polaroid/sprite_polaroid_total.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    var rotator = $('#rotator');
    var container = $(document);
    var viewport = $(window);

    var images = 72;
    var imageHeight = 30000 / images;
    var scrollHeight = container.height() - viewport.height() + imageHeight;
    var step = images / scrollHeight;

    viewport.scroll(function(event) {

        var x = -Math.floor(step * viewport.scrollTop()) * imageHeight;
        rotator.css('background-position', x + 'px 0');

    });

});
```